# Using an instance variable in another view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to create an instance variable inside the create method of one controller and then to use it in the view of another controller.  Is this possible?

I'm creating the `@content` variable within the `MicropostsController`:

```
class MicropostsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]
  before_filter :correct_user, only: :destroy

  def create
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(params[:micropost])
    @content = 'test' #params[:micropost][:content]
    #pattern = /\A@\w+/

    #if params[:micropost][:content] =~ pattern
     # @content = params[:micropost][:content]
    #end

    if @micropost.save
      flash[:success] = "Micropost created!"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      @feed_items = []
      render 'static_pages/home'
    end
  end
```

And I'm trying to use it in a partial that's used in the view of class `StaticPages` but it doesn't work:

```
<li id="<%= feed_item.id %>">
  <%= link_to gravatar_for(feed_item.user), feed_item.user %>
  <span class="user">
      <%= link_to feed_item.user.name, feed_item.user %>
  </span>
  <span class="content"><%= feed_item.content %></span>
  <span class="timestamp">
    Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(feed_item.created_at) %> ago.
    <% if @content %>
      <%= @content %>
    <% else %>
      <%= 'no content' %>
    <% end %>
  </span>
  <% if current_user?(feed_item.user) %>
    <%= link_to "delete", feed_item, method: :delete,
                data: { confirm: "You sure?" },
                title: feed_item.content %>
  <% end %>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is not related to use an instance variable in the view of a different controller, but to use an instance variable in a partial:

You can use the `@content` instance variable in the view rendered by `static_pages/home`, whichever is the calling Controller. But you can't use the intance variable in a partial. You need to give it as a local variable of your partial, and use it as a local variable in the partial. There is several syntaxes to pass local variables in a partial, see example in [Rails guide on layouts and rendering 3.4.4](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials).

In the code you posted, `feed_item` is likely to be such a local variable of your partial.

Answer (score 0):

Either put it in the database, or use flash its if the 2 methods are one after the other..

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the instance variable set in one controller in another controller's view.
You need to have it set in StaticPagesController or you could use a helper.

This might help : [Rails: Set a common instance variable across several controller actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914226/rails-set-a-common-instance-variable-across-several-controller-actions)